# Return active vs inactive records count against a given date in a single column

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I currently have the following **UsersData** table which gives aggregated historical data at a given particular date:

| Date | UserID | Name | isActive |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-10-01 | 1 | Sam | 1 |
| 2021-10-01 | 2 | Dan | 1 |
| 2021-10-08 | 1 | Sam | 0 |
| 2021-10-08 | 2 | Dan | 1 |

### **Requirement**

My requirement is to create another aggregated data which will show active vs inactive record for a the above given dates - in a single row. So something like below:

| Date | Active | Inactive | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-10-01 | 2 | 0 | 2 |
| 2021-10-08 | 1 | 1 | 2 |

### My SQL queries so far

Now when I try the following individual queries it works fine:

```
select date, count(distinct userid) AS ActiveCount from User where isActive= 1 group by date
select date, count(distinct userid) AS InactiveCount from User where isActive= 0 group by date
```

But since I need to display the statistics in a single row for each date, I tried the following query but there's something which I seem to be doing wrong here:

```
select
date,
(select count(distinct userid) from User where isActive= 1 group by date) AS Active,
(select count(distinct userid) from User where isActive= 0 group by date) AS Inactive,
count(distinct userid) AS total 
from userdata
group by date
order by date
```

With this I get the output for inactive and active records as the sum of both results - Active = 3 (2 from first date + 1 from second date)  and 'Inactive' = 2 (0 from first date +1 from second date)
Whereas 'TotalCount' value is accurate.

Here's the output which I get with the above query:

| Date | Active | Inactive | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-10-01 | 3 | 1 | 2 |
| 2021-10-08 | 3 | 1 | 2 |

What am I doing wrong here?
What would be the correct query? I'm executing these currently in Databricks Delta Lake SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select date
    , count(distinct userid) filter (where isActive= 1) AS ActiveCount 
    , count(distinct userid) filter (where isActive= 0) AS InactiveCount 
    , count(distinct userid) Total
from User 
group by date
```

Comment: Accepting this answer since this will be more suitable for my further planned changes to the query.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about databricks, but I think this should work...

```
select date
, sum(case when isActive=1 then 1 else 0 end) AS ActiveCount 
, sum(case when isActive=0 then 1 else 0 end) AS InactiveCount 
, count(distinct userId) as total
from User 
group by date
```

([SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/61b9bf/1/0))